# Cannot start instrumented android test on gitlab ci/cd

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Our applications is app module with submodule in another repo, that fetching recursiely. We have a Docker with Gitlab, and I've been trying to start android test on emulators, but it says that it cannot found emulators. Nobody did it before on our gitlab machine. Please help, how can I fix it?

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# Image
image: images.company.com/gitlab/builder/android:31_02r

# vars
variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

# cache
cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_ID}
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

before_script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$PWD/.gradle
  - export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk"
  - bundle install

# Main steps
stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - build
  - uiTest
  - cleanup

linting:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane demoLint
  only:
    - merge_requests

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane demoUnitTests
  only:
    - merge_requests

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean assembleRelease
  only:
    - merge_requests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/

instrumentation_tests:
  stage: uiTest
  script:
    - echo y | sdkmanager --install 'system-images;android-34;google_apis;x86_64'
    - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force --name testAVD --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package "system-images;android-34;google_apis;x86_64"
    - export APK_PATH="app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-universal-release.apk"
    - emulator -avd testAVD -no-audio -no-window &
    - chmod +x ./ci/android-wait-for-emulator.sh
    - adb devices
    - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
    - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
    - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
    - ./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.apkFile=$APK_PATH
    - chmod +x ./ci/stop-emulators.sh
  only:
    - merge_requests
  artifacts:
    name: "reports_${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}"
    when: on_failure
    expire_in: 4 days
    paths:
      - app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/

cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - rm -rf app/build/outputs/
    - rm -rf /usr/local/android-sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis/x86_64
    - rm -rf ~/.android/avd/testAVD.avd
  only:
    - merge_requests
  when: always
```

android-wait-for-emulator.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set +e

bootanim=""
failcounter=0
timeout_in_sec=500

until [[ "$bootanim" =~ "stopped" ]]; do
  bootanim=`adb -e shell getprop init.svc.bootanim 2>&1 &`
  echo "$bootanim"
  if [[ "$bootanim" =~ "not found"
    || "$bootanim" =~ "device not found"
    || "$bootanim" =~ "no emulators found"
    || "$bootanim" =~ "device offline"
    || "$bootanim" =~ "running" ]]; then
    let "failcounter += 5"
    echo "Waiting for emulator to start"
    if [[ $failcounter -gt timeout_in_sec ]]; then
      echo "Timeout ($timeout_in_sec seconds) reached; failed to start emulator"
      jobs -l
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
  sleep 5
done

echo "Emulator is ready!"
exit 0
```

stop-emulators.sh:

```
for ((PORT=5554; PORT<=5584; PORT+=2)); do
    echo killing emulator-$PORT...
    adb -s emulator-$PORT emu kill || true
done
```

I have this errors with manifest and emulators:

```
> Task :app:transformClassesWithAPMSPluginForDebugAndroidTest
can not find manifest file: /builds/android/chat-center/chatcenter-demo/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
fail to read manifest file: Premature end of file.
fail to get activity lists: null
fail to get package name: null
fail to get application name: null
> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:packageDebugAndroidTest
> Task :app:createDebugAndroidTestApkListingFileRedirect
> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Comment: Are you sure `$APK_PATH` is still set by the time you reach the `./gradlew` build command? Normally, each array element in a YAML script array is run in its own shell and an environment variable exported in an earlier shell won't pass through to a later command. You can either use a multi-line with the `script: |-` syntax or just move that value into the later command. The `|-` will include line-breaks in the value so you can just write the whole script as one array element and it will execute it all in one shell.

Comment: But app is being built normally. I can see APK in artifacts

Comment: Can you confirm that `$APK_PATH` is being set with an `echo $APK_PATH` in a later line. I'm pretty sure those aren't preserved, but this may not be the cause of the error. I am not actually sure why you need to set android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.apkFile in the later command. Also, add a debug line with `adb devices` and perhaps a command like `adb shell echo hi` to verify that connectivity to the emulator is working just before the `./gradlew` statement.

Comment: $ echo $APK_PATH
app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-universal-release.apk
$ adb devices
adb: no devices/emulators found
adb: no devices/emulators found
adb: no devices/emulators found
adb: no devices/emulators found
List of devices attached
$ adb shell echo hi
adb: no devices/emulators found

Comment: I think I see the issue here. You mark `./ci/android-wait-for-emulator.sh` as executable, but you never actually call that script to wait for the emulator come up. Add that just before running other `adb` commands.

Comment: You aren't calling any bash scripts, as mentioned by penguin. Make sure you call the `./ci/android-wait-for-emulator.sh` and see what `adb devices` outputs.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I haven't called scripts until now. But now I have just timeout, and adb devices shows nothing

Comment: check the comment from the guy mewitte here.
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/getting-incompatible-avd-error-while-running-instrumentation-test/7341/3

Answer (score -1):

Update gradle to **8.2**
And everything will work as simple as that.

Comment: I cannot do this. Company policy. And locally it works. But on Gitlab CI/CD - no